# Attribution: Quoting a Fictional Character

Tags: quotes

Famously:

> "Try not. Do or do not. There is no try."
>           -- Yoda

Thing is, this is from a movie. A writer wrote it and a voice actor spoke it. Is there a correct form of attribution for a case like this? If so, what?

Comment: I believe you can say: "Yoda, from _Star Wars_". You might add the year of release as well, in a more formal context.

Comment: Also see [Attributing quotes to fictional characters](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/8440),

Comment: If you're speaking, one fairly common way to say it is: "As George Lucas's Yoda says ..." or "As Tom Clancy's Jack Ryan tells us before he blows up a plane.."  Or similarly "As Princess Leia from Star Wars says..." or "As Roy Batty says in Bladerunner..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author Robert Asprin famously sprinkles his books with [quotations](http://www.lib.ru/ASPRIN/epigraphs.txt), many of which are fictitious. They're attributed in the form you show in your question:

> "In times of crisis, it is of utmost importance not to lose one's
>   head."
>
> --M. Antoinette
>
> "A little help at the right time is better than a lot of help at the
>   wrong time."
>
> --Tevye

Et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

So "everyone" knows who Yoda is.  But in a more formal context, or with a less well-known character or work, you might want to use something more like:

```
"Try not. Do or do not. There is no try."
    -- Yoda, In Star Wars, George Lucas
```

or even

```
    -- Yoda [1]

[1] Proper reference to Star Wars.
```